# Cannot install sqlite3

Tags: ruby, sqlite

**OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS**

```
$sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev

The following packages have unmet dependencies: libsqlite3-dev : Depends: libsqlite3-0 (=3.7.9-2ubuntu1) but 3.7.9-2ubuntu1.1 is to be installed



$sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-0

Building dependency tree
Reading state information... 
Done libsqlite3-0 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 103 not upgraded.
```

I have also try to download the newest package on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/i386/libsqlite3-dev/3.7.15-1

and have read this: https://getsatisfaction.com/jolicloud/topics/installing_libsqlite3_dev_doesnt_work

Ubuntu responsed: "cannot install libc6:i386" or "is not statisfiable..."

Comment: It shows you have a 103 upgrades. What's up with that?

Comment: now i have updated all the patches by Upgrate Manager. I cannot remove libsqlite3-0 because it's already there. Have tried sudo apt-get remove libsqlite3-0, still cannot install libsqlite3-dev

Comment: did you try sudo apt-get purge libsqlite3-0?

Comment: did you try sudo apt-get purge libsqlite3-0? – don.joey Dec 20 '12 at 13:55 DONT RUN THIS!!! Snapshot before you do. It purged a ton of stuff from my install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with some of the 64-bit packages being out of sync with the 32-bit packages (3.7.9-2ubuntu1 vs. 3.7.9-2ubuntu1.1).

The following answer is shamelessly cut'n'pasted from the thread at http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?60125-Can-t-install-anything-bad-libsqlite3-0-amd64 which I recommend for a more thorough description (as well as steps to verify that this is indeed your problem.)

1. Download the 64-bit version:

   ```
   apt-get download libsqlite3-0:amd64
   ```
2. Download the 32-bit version:

   ```
   apt-get download libsqlite3-0:i386
   ```
3. Forcibly remove the existing 64-bit version:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --force-depends --purge libsqlite3-0:amd64
   ```
4. Forcibly remove the existing 32-bit version:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --force-depends --purge libsqlite3-0:i386
   ```
5. Manually install the 64-bit version:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --install libsqlite3-0*amd64.deb
   ```
6. Manually install the 32-bit version:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --install libsqlite3-0*i386.deb
   ```

Then see if your install of the -dev works, since one of those should match what it's looking for.

Comment: Step 2 and 4 will not cancel out?

Comment: Step 2 is a download only, not an install.